# webpack - WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am having a little issue with webpack. 
Everything works smoothly when I include all my libraries in my html page, but when I create a lib.bundle using webpack I get the above mentioned error.

Now, I found out that basically the issue comes from the fact that I am still including the angular library in my HTML page, while everything else is packed in the bundle, see below:

webpack entry file:

```
 ...
 require('./js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js'); // Add ng file upload
 require('./js/angular-animate.min.js'); // Add angular animate
 require('./js/angular-ui-router.min.js'); // Add angular UI router
 ...
```

My HTML index file:

```
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>window.angular || document.write('<script src="dist/lib/angular.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

I am trying to use a CDN to include big libraries when possible, but maybe there's a way to move that part of code in my entry.js file?

P.S.: seems like angular-moment is the one creating the issue.

Thank you

Comment: If you're loading libraries from both, obviously you'll have a problem. Since peerDependencies is basically deprecated, wouldn't it be a devDependency?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your comment. I didn't set any dependencies form the packages I am importing, I thought by default they were disabled. As I understand there's a way to disable them manually in my npm package?